# Delphi Webbrowser scrollIntoView(true) not working

Tags: delphi, scroll, twebbrowser

I'm trying to find a text in a webbrowser with Delphi 2010 and scroll into it. The code finds the text and scrolls to it, but the text stays on the bottom of the webview (in the last line). I'd like to show the text on the top (first line) of the webview.

I think the code for this would be "scrollIntoView(true)", but it doesn't affect at all what i'm trying to do.

What should i do? Thanks. Here's my code

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton10Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    doc: IHTMLDocument2;
    selection: IHTMLSelectionObject;
    textRange: IHtmlTxtRange;
    scrollpos: Integer;
    Art : string;
begin

Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
Selection := Doc.Selection;
TextRange := selection.createRange as IHTMLTxtRange;

Art := edit2.Text;

TextRange.collapse(false);
if TextRange.findText(Art) then
begin
TextRange.select;
TextRange.scrollIntoView(true);

 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get `TextRange.scrollIntoView(True)` to work, either.  However, the code below seems to work for a document of the format

> Line1
>   
> Line2
>   
> Line3
>   
> Line4
>   
> Line5
>   
> ... 
>   
> Line 100

provided the document isn't scrolled to a point where `Line100` is above the bottom line in the browser window.  It works fine, f.i., to find `Line20` and position it at the top of the browser window.

As you can see, it works by getting an `IHTMLTextRangeMetrics` interface from the `TextRange` and using its `offsetTop` property to scroll `doc2`'s parent window vertically.

Code:

```
//  doc2 is a field of Form1 of type `IHTMLDocument2`
procedure TForm1.FindText(Text : String);
var
  selection: IHTMLSelectionObject;
  textRange: IHtmlTxtRange;
  scrollpos: Integer;
  Metrics : IHTMLTextRangeMetrics;
begin

  Selection := Doc2.Selection;
  TextRange := selection.createRange as IHTMLTxtRange;

  TextRange.collapse(false);
  if TextRange.findText(Text, 1, 0) then begin
    TextRange.select;
    TextRange.scrollIntoView(True);
    TextRange.QueryInterface(IHTMLTextRangeMetrics, Metrics);
    if Metrics <> Nil then
      doc2.parentWindow.scrollBy(0, Metrics.offsetTop);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why, it only works if the code is executed twice. But it works! Thank you so much!